# Problems trying to insert data with JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-flex, jpa, ejb

I am a newbie on JPA and i have this problem for what i couldn't find a solution:

I am using EJB with JPA in order to work with a MySQL Server Database. I am inserting data through a WebService made by myself in JAVA and invoked from a Flex application.

I have a table on the database called SiProducto, where i store products. The definition of the table on the database is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "SiProducto" (
"Codigo_HE" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
"Codigo_Producto" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
"Descripcion" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
"Descripcion_Larga" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
"Codigo_Tipo_Producto" INT NULL,
"Codigo_Unidad_Medida" INT NULL,
"Codigo_Familia" INT NULL,
"Exento" TINYINT NULL,
"Ultimo_Precio_Compra" FLOAT NULL,
"Ultimo_Precio_Venta" FLOAT NULL,
"PMP" FLOAT NULL,
"Fecha_Ultima_Compra" DATETIME NULL,
"Fecha_Ultima_Venta" DATETIME NULL,
"Foto_Producto" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
"Observaciones" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
"NoValida_Stock" TINYINT NULL,
"Imagen" IMAGE NULL,
"Activo" TINYINT NULL,
"Codigo_Moneda" INT NULL,
"FechaHora" DATETIME NULL,
"Usuario" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
"Estacion" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
"FechaHora_Modifica" DATETIME NULL,
"Usuario_Modifica" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
"Estacion_Modifica" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
"Codigo_Impuesto" SMALLINT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("Codigo_HE", "Codigo_Producto")
);
```

The definition of the columns of the same table in the entity class that references it is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SiProducto", schema = "dbo", catalog = "FACEL")
public class SiProducto implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private SiProductoId id;
private SiFamilia siFamilia;
private SiUnidadesDeMedidas siUnidadesDeMedidas;
private SiMoneda siMoneda;
private SiTipoProducto siTipoProducto;
private String descripcion;
private String descripcionLarga;
private Short exento;
private Double ultimoPrecioCompra;
private Double ultimoPrecioVenta;
private Double pmp;
private Timestamp fechaUltimaCompra;
private Timestamp fechaUltimaVenta;
private String fotoProducto;
private String observaciones;
private Short noValidaStock;
private String imagen;
private Short activo;
private Timestamp fechaHora;
private String usuario;
private String estacion;
private Timestamp fechaHoraModifica;
private String usuarioModifica;
private String estacionModifica;
private Short codigoImpuesto;
private Set<VeDetallePedido> veDetallePedidos = new HashSet<VeDetallePedido>(0);
private Set<VeDetalleCotizacion> veDetalleCotizacions = new HashSet<VeDetalleCotizacion>(0);
private Set<BoExistencia> boExistencias = new HashSet<BoExistencia>(0);
//...
```

Please, notice the following attributes: siFamilia, siMoneda, siTipoProducto and siUnidadesDeMedidas. Those are instances of entity classes SiFamilia, SiMoneda, SiTipoProducto and SiUnidadesDeMedidas, respectively and reference the tables with their respective same names in the database.
The tables SiMoneda and SiTipoProducto have a simple Integer primary key in the database and, in the SiProducto class, the getter and setter of the objects siMoneda and siTipoProducto are defined as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_Moneda")
public SiMoneda getSiMoneda() {
    return this.siMoneda;
}

public void setSiMoneda(SiMoneda siMoneda) {
    this.siMoneda = siMoneda;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_Tipo_Producto")
public SiTipoProducto getSiTipoProducto() {
    return this.siTipoProducto;
}

public void setSiTipoProducto(SiTipoProducto siTipoProducto) {
    this.siTipoProducto = siTipoProducto;
}
```

On the other hand, the tables SiFamilia and SiUnidadesDeMedidas each have a primary key composed of one VARCHAR column and one INTEGER column. The getter and setter of the objects siFamilia and siUnidadesDeMedidas on the class SiProducto are defined as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_HE", referencedColumnName = "Codigo_HE", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_Familia", referencedColumnName = "Codigo_Familia", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
public SiFamilia getSiFamilia() {
    return this.siFamilia;
}

public void setSiFamilia(SiFamilia siFamilia) {
    this.siFamilia = siFamilia;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_HE", referencedColumnName = "Codigo_HE", insertable =false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Codigo_Unidad_Medida", referencedColumnName = "Codigo_Unidad_Medida", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
public SiUnidadesDeMedidas getSiUnidadesDeMedidas() {
    return this.siUnidadesDeMedidas;
}
```

The FLEX function that invokes the WebService i use for inserting a SiProducto in the database is the following:

```
public function crear():void{
            var prod:WebProductoExtended=new WebProductoExtended();
            prod.codigo=codigo2.text;
            prod.nombre=nombreProducto2.text;
            prod.precioVenta=Number(precioVenta2.text);
            prod.codFamilia=comboFamilia2.selectedItem.codigo;
            prod.codMoneda=comboMoneda2.selectedItem.codigo;
            prod.codUMedida=comboUnidad2.selectedItem.codigo;
            prod.tipoProducto=comboTipoProducto.selectedItem.codigo;
            prod.descripcionLarga=descripcionLarga.text;
            prod.observaciones=observaciones.text;
            if(activo.selected)
                prod.activo=1;
            else
                prod.activo=0;
            if(validaStock.selected)
                prod.noValidaStock=0;
            else
                prod.noValidaStock=1;
            if(exento.selected)
                prod.exento=1;
            else
                prod.exento=0;
            //This is where i invoke the WebService
            var token:AsyncToken=wSProducto.createProduct(prod, "0000100001");
            var responder:AsyncResponder=new AsyncResponder(onCreateResult, onCreateFault, "createProduct");
            token.addResponder(responder);  
        }
```

The WebMethod that creates a SiProducto in the database is defined as:

```
@WebMethod()
public WEBBase createProduct(WEBProductoExtended input, String codigoHe){
    WEBBase result=new WEBBase();
    try{
        SiProducto siprod=new SiProducto();
        SiProductoId id=new SiProductoId(codigoHe, input.getCodigo());
        SiFamiliaId idFamilia=new SiFamiliaId(codigoHe, input.getCodFamilia());
        SiFamilia familia=facadeFamilia.findById(idFamilia);
        SiMoneda moneda=facadeMoneda.findById(input.getCodMoneda());
        SiUnidadesDeMedidasId idUMedida=new SiUnidadesDeMedidasId(codigoHe, input.getCodUMedida());
        SiUnidadesDeMedidas uMedida=facadeUMedida.findById(idUMedida);
        SiTipoProducto tipoProducto=facadeTipoProducto.findById(input.getTipoProducto());
        siprod.setId(id);
        siprod.setSiFamilia(familia);
        siprod.setSiMoneda(moneda);
        siprod.setSiUnidadesDeMedidas(uMedida);
        siprod.setDescripcion(input.getNombre());
        siprod.setUltimoPrecioVenta(input.getPrecioVenta());
        siprod.setSiTipoProducto(tipoProducto);
        siprod.setDescripcionLarga(input.getDescripcionLarga());
        siprod.setActivo(input.getActivo());
        siprod.setExento(input.getExento());
        siprod.setNoValidaStock(input.getNoValidaStock());
        siprod.setObservaciones(input.getObservaciones());
        siprod.setFechaHora(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        facade.save(siprod);
        result.setCodigo(0);
        result.setMensaje("Registro guardado con exito");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        result.setCodigo(-1);
        result.setMensaje("Error al crear producto: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

NOTES: "Registro guardado con exito" = "Insert successful"; "Error al crear producto" = "Error when trying to insert product".

I got an "Insert Successful" from the WebMethod, and when i debug the SiProducto object i want to insert, it has all data i sent from the FLEX function, but still, when i check the database, the new SiProducto has all of that data **except the columns "Codigo_Familia" and "Codigo_Unidad_Medida", that are NULL values**.

The question is: *how can i insert those values using JPA in the database given the conditions explained above?*

Thanks in advance

EDIT: In responde to Chris's comment, I tried to change it to insertable=true and i got the following exception:

15:09:24,790 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."EARPos.ear/EJBPos.jar#EJBPos": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."EARPos.ear/EJBPos.jar#EJBPos": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EJBPos] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EJBPos] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: cl.eugcom.pos.ejb.model.SiProducto column: Codigo_HE (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1789)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 9 more

UPDATE: I tried to make, for siFamilia, the field Codigo_HE neither insertable nor updatable, and the field codigo_familia insertable and updatable and i got this exception:

10:44:07,618 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."EARPos.ear/EJBPos.jar#EJBPos": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."EARPos.ear/EJBPos.jar#EJBPos": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EJBPos] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EJBPos] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **Mixing updatable and non updatable columns in a property is not allowed: cl.eugcom.pos.ejb.model.SiProducto.siFamilia**
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.checkPropertyConsistency(Ejb3Column.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2817)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3568)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1379)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 9 more

I still don't understand Chris' last answer (about changing the mappings so only one column has it's foreign key insertable and updatable)

**SOLVED**: I gave up with using JPA the way i was using it, so i did a little research and i found a way to insert data on conditions like these. Instead of using the method save of the EntityManager Class, i used the method createNativeQuery with the SQL Sentence i need to execute. The Query class has similiar behavior as the PreparedStatement interface, so i put question marks in the sentence and i use the setParameter method in order to put the parameters of the query on their respective positions.

This is the result:

```
public void save2(SiProducto entity){
    LogUtil.log("saving SiProducto instance", Level.INFO, null);
    try{
        String ql="insert into SiProducto "
                + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        Query q=entityManager.createNativeQuery(ql);
        q.setParameter(1, entity.getId().getCodigoHe());
        q.setParameter(2, entity.getId().getCodigoProducto());
        q.setParameter(3, entity.getDescripcion());
        q.setParameter(4, entity.getDescripcionLarga());
        q.setParameter(5, entity.getSiTipoProducto().getCodigoTipoProducto());
        q.setParameter(6, entity.getSiUnidadesDeMedidas().getId().getCodigoUnidadMedida());
        q.setParameter(7, entity.getSiFamilia().getId().getCodigoFamilia());
        q.setParameter(8, entity.getExento());
        q.setParameter(9, entity.getUltimoPrecioCompra());
        q.setParameter(10, entity.getUltimoPrecioVenta());
        q.setParameter(11, entity.getPmp());
        q.setParameter(12, entity.getFechaUltimaCompra());
        q.setParameter(13, entity.getFechaUltimaVenta());
        q.setParameter(14, entity.getFotoProducto());
        q.setParameter(15, entity.getObservaciones());
        q.setParameter(16, entity.getNoValidaStock());
        q.setParameter(17, entity.getImagen());
        q.setParameter(18, entity.getActivo());
        q.setParameter(19, entity.getSiMoneda().getCodigoMoneda());
        q.setParameter(20, entity.getFechaHora());
        q.setParameter(21, entity.getUsuario());
        q.setParameter(22, entity.getEstacion());
        q.setParameter(23, entity.getFechaHoraModifica());
        q.setParameter(24, entity.getUsuarioModifica());
        q.setParameter(25, entity.getEstacionModifica());
        q.setParameter(26, entity.getCodigoImpuesto());
        q.executeUpdate();

    }catch (RuntimeException re) {
        LogUtil.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

And it worked for me. Thanks anyway to you all.

Comment: You have the only mappings to "Codigo_Familia" marked as insertable=false updatable=false so there is no way to set that field in your object model

Comment: I edited my publicacion adding my response to your comment,

Comment: The exception tells you what you need to do.  You have set the "Codigo_HE" fields in your mappings to insertable=true, and you have multiple mappings using that field.  Only one mapping should control setting the field, and the others marked insertable=false.

Comment: That means that in ALL Entity beans must i set the insertable=true for "Codigo_HE", or must i do this only for those attributes inside SiProducto that have "Codigo_HE" as primary key in the database and were declared with insertable=false? I ask this question because this column is present in most tables in the database,

Comment: A column in a table can only have a single writable mapping, any others that would use that field should be marked as read only by setting it insertable=false, updateable=false as you originally set.  The two mappings you had, siFamilia and siUnidadesDeMedidas both are using the  "Codigo_HE" field as a foreign key, but there can only be one in control of setting the value for that field in the database.  Change your mappings so that only 1 mapping controls the field, and the others are not insertable.

Comment: I already did that only with siFamilia (i left siUnidadesDeMedidas untouched) and i got that exception. Does it work if i change the mappings letting only Codigo_HE as  insertable=false, updateable=false and codigo_familia (for siFamilia) and codigo_unidad_medida (for siUnidadesDeMedidas) as  insertable=true, updateable=true?